# JTable header is not showing in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, jtable

I want to add a `JTable` into a `JScrollPane`, but the tableheader is not showing. Could anybody can help me figure out this?

```
            JScrollPane tablePane = new JScrollPane();
            tablePane.setViewportView(table);
            tablePane.setRowHeaderView(table);
            tablePane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(950, 450));

            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 500));
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tablePane);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should help.

`JScrollPane tablePane = new JScrollPane(table);
//tablePane.setViewportView(table);
//tablePane.setRowHeaderView(table);`

Comment: yes, it works! Thank you! the problem is this line: `tablePane.setRowHeaderView(table);`  But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to make the JTable scrollable. When you look into the documentation of JTable, you'll notice that JTable is already scrollable. So you don't need to add a JTable to a JScrollPane.

Also you should not add the JTable as `ViewportView` **and** as `RowHeaderView` of the JScrollPane simultaneously. The `RowHeaderView` of JScrollPane does not just take the `RowHeaderView` of the JTable. Instead you'll get two JTables side by side.
To fix this just set the `viewportView` of the JScrollPane or leave the JScrollPane completly out and use the JTable as standalone container.

Comment: the problem is this line: `tablePane.setRowHeaderView(table); ` But I don't know why.

Comment: @pilates I updated my answer. Hope it is understandable.

Comment: yes, it's understandable. but i think you can not leave JScrollPane out.